# freeNx client closes automatically in Windows 7 when connecting to centos 5

Tags: centos, freenx

I have installed freenx installed on centos 5
When I try to login from  a freeNx client in Windows 7, I get authenticated and a intial splash screen for NX shows up but the window closed down automatically.

Since authentication succeeds I am lost as to what is going wrong and why my FreeNX client closes.

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Bala

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before after migrating my laptop to Windows 7. Apparently it has something to do with suspended sessions. So, I cleaned all suspended sessions and it was okay after that.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is the obvious issue: I just had this problem yesterday.  My issue was that the client had KDE selected for the environment, but neither KDE nor X were actually installed.

Running:

```
# yum groupinstall "KDE (K Desktop Environment)"
# yum groupinstall "X Window System"
```

...solved my problem.